# ipad: present a view with zoom out effect and remove with zoom in effect

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview

I want to display a view with zoom out effect on click of a button and dissolve the view with a zoom in effect can you guide me to achieve this.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a CAAnimation to the view's layer:

```
CABasicAnimation *ani = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
[ani setDuration:0.5];
[ani setRepeatCount:1];
[ani setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
[ani setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1]];
[ani setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[myView layer] addAnimation:ani forKey:@"zoom"];
```

This adds an animation that makes the view shrink into its center. You might want to add set a delegate and implement `animationDidStop:finished:` in which you then hide the view and reset the layer's scale (see [CAAnimation reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)).

To create the opposite effect simply exchange the from and to values.

Also note that while the scale is not 1.0, the `frame` property is undefined. That is, if you try to move it or change its size while the layer's scale is not 1.0, strange things will happen.